# Xcode won't recognize a new Swift class

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a new Swift class in a new file

```
import Foundation

class RecordedAudio: NSObject{
    var filePathUrl: NSURL!
    var title: String!
}
```

and now I want use it inside another class by creating a new object.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class recordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    var recordedAudio: RecordedAudio! // new object gives error
```

But Xcode is giving me the error "Use of undeclared type RecordedAudio" so I got stuck there. A similar question has been posted here: [How do I import a Swift file from another Swift file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029781/how-do-i-import-a-swift-file-from-another-swift-file)
but none of those solutions worked for me. BTW, this is part of the Udacity swift class. Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes, all you need is a good restart of Xcode. **⌘-Q**uit Xcode, then reopen and see if the issue persists.

Comment: For me, sometimes I have to restart it 4-5 times, pretty buggy

Comment: Thanks for replying guys, I did restart xcode a few times but didn't work.

Comment: Clean, CMD+k worked for me

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In the Project Navigator on the left, select the file where you declared RecordedAudio.

Now, in the File inspector on the right, look at the Target Membership. The app target (not the Test target) should be *checked*, similar to this:

[image]

If not, check it! And now all will be well.

Comment: Thanks matt, that worked. On the new class, I had both "target" and "test target" checked so I unchecked "test target" and keep only "target" . That did the trick.

Comment: For future readers, also try unchecking and checking the target again if it's already checked.

Answer (score 5):

If your class is in another Module, please make sure that your class and the class initializers have the **public** access modifier.

Comment: Yep, converting some of my own code to a library and this was it for me

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to remove the references from the project navigator, and then add them again (the target membership was not the problem).

Answer (score 4):

I just had to do the Full Monty to get it to work...

1. Comment out referencing lines
2. Fix other bugs to ensure a build
3. Cmd+Shft+K (Clean build folder)
4. Nay...let's delete the build folder: /Users/[YOU]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-name-ADM2KD...
5. Restart Xcode
6. Build
7. Uncomment our referencing lines

Also maybe add @objc to the line above your class definition and maybe make it `public class` just to be explicit and possible add `public` to your methods as well. Oh and make sure you are subclassing `NSObject`.

If you are stuck getting your initialiser to show up, I've also just noticed that Swift 4.2 has lots more problems here. I switched back to Swift 3. No problems...

Comment: Sadly, this is what I had to do to get it to work also.

Comment: Adding the public keyword did the trick for me. I moved the class to other module then Xcode won't recognise in others. I spent quite a few hours trying the above steps already as you mentioned. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to check the same target memberships on the class as in the ViewController (I had a TodayExtension)

Answer (score 0):

Tried the ownership toggling, cleaning, restarted x-code, deleted and re-adding reference but no result.

A `pod install` fixed it for me, weird because my class was not from another module or library.