# CarbonKit via Pods throws an error after import

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, macos-carbon

I'm having an issue with CarbonKit via its pod. As shown below CarbonKit is downloaded and installed correctly, according to pod. It appears in my project and is included within my Obj-C header file. However when I try to use the framework it fails with the error:

`Use of undeclared type 'CarbonTabSwipeDelegate'`.

I have the framework imported with the usual `import CarbonKit` - along with the header file for pods.

[image: Pod project screenshot]

Here's the pod in my project, it seems to be there with all the supporting files.

Here I've included it in the Embedded binaries file:
[image: Embedded Binaries]

And here is my pod file:
[image: Pod file screenshot]

Any ideas as to why I'm getting the error? I don't see how I can include it in any other way.

Comment: Do you need to import in Swift? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24029970/2264888

Comment: In my header file (the file to import all pods into a Swift project) I have #import <CarbonKit/CarbonKit.h> but for some reason it doesn't propagate around my project.

Comment: So you have a bridging header? Try just #import <CarbonKit.h> sometimes it works like that. Or try it with #import "CarbonKit". If not, check the path to the bridging header in Build Settings to see if it's correct. Are you using other #imports in the bridging header and are those working?

Comment: Yeah I meant bridging header. The import works but changing around throws an error so that mean it must be picking it up right? When I try and import the library it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/LBdl7fW.png I know the bridging file should cover it but could that be related to the issue you think?

Comment: Might be the file path to the bridging header - common case for Xcode not being able to find things. Sometimes also if you manually copy over frameworks, Xcode can't find the framework, but since you used Cocoapods it *should* work, but this happens quite frequently. Usually a file path issue somewhere - I'm not good at debugging that type of stuff, sorry.