# Use constants in Swift like Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, constants, global

How i can use global constants like:

```
#define EXAMPLE 123
```

from Objective-C in Swift???

I need to use string constants, which must be defined in AppDelegate to use in all App with `#include "AppDelegate.h"` in each class files.

Comment: Make one constant file and Declare all constants there. If you r using objective c then make one pch file & import that constant file OR if you use swift then you can directly access that constant without importing anything

Answer (score 3):

I suggest making a structure, in a seperate file, with its properties as `let` constants. So something like this

```
struct myConstants {
    static let firstConstant = "hello"
    static let secondConstant = "goodbye"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to use it, but i can't set your answer as helpful. Reputation resist it. Sorry

Comment: No worries. Happy to help.

Comment: I must use #import or #include to see this constants I'm other files??? In obj-C i must #import "GlobalConst.swift" to see it in other files...

Comment: No. you should be able to just refer to it directly ... ?

Comment: Maybe something wrong, because xCode say that i used unresolved identifier.
I just create new source file named GlobalConst.swift, put structure from your example in this file. and save it )))

Comment: That error is really annoying but it shouldn't really be happening. I cannot help much without seeing it for myself but read this and its discussed in depth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029781/how-do-i-import-a-swift-file-from-another-swift-file

Comment: Everything is all right now! Thanks!
I forgot use struct name to find this constants )))
It's hard to change mind from Obj to Swift at first steps )))

Comment: Great. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a `Struct class` and make each `property/function static`.

```
struct Global {
    static var test = "Some value"
}
```

Call it `Global.test`

Comment: I don't like the 'struct class' expression. Structs are not classes.