# Swift import class from project outside Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, command-line-interface

I'm learning Swift and I want to import a protocol from one file into another. I've looked at this thread [How do I import a Swift file from another Swift file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029781/how-do-i-import-a-swift-file-from-another-swift-file), but all the answers are focused on setting a `target` and other XCode related features.

I'm running swift files on the command line: `swift myfile.swift`, which is pretty clearly a different execution environment than Xcode. Any guidance on importing a neighboring structure?

```
myDir
├── CoolProtocol.swift
├── my file.swift
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this blog post: https://monospacedmonologues.com/2019/01/running-swift-without-xcode/

Essentially, the answer is to compile the code with `swiftc` including a "dummy main file." And define the `main` function in the code you want to run:

```
├── Helpers
│   ├── CoolProtocol.swift
│   └── main.swift
├── my_file.swift
```

In main.switf:

```
main()
```

In my_file.swift

```
func main() {
// the main functionality
}
```

compile like this:

```
swiftc -o myprogram my_file.swift Helpers/*.swift
```

Comment: once compiled, you can run the program like this `./my_file`